# How can I use multiple Community Mongo replica sets in one Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I've been running a community version of the MongoDB replica set in Kubernetes for over a year now. For reference, I am deploying with these Helm charts:
https://github.com/mongodb/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/community-operator
https://github.com/mongodb/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/community-operator-crds

I now have a need to spin up a couple extra replica sets. I cannot reuse the existing rs because this new deployment is software from one of our subcontractors and we want to keep it separate. When I try to start a new rs, all the rs on the namespace get into a bad state, failing readiness probes.

Do the different replica sets each require their own operator? In an attempt to test that theory, I modified the values.yaml and deployed an operator for each rs but I'm still getting the error.

I think I am missing a config on the DB deployment that tells it which operator to use, but I can't find that config option in the helm chart (referencing the 2nd link from earlier https://github.com/mongodb/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/community-operator-crds/templates/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml)

**EDIT:** For a little extra info, it seems like the mongodb can be used without issue. Kubernetes is just showing an error, saying the readiness probes have failed.

Comment: Have you looked at using the community operator rather than using helm to install mongo?

Comment: I am using the community operator, which I linked in my post.

Comment: Oh, you said that you're deploying community mongo with helm -- I didn't realise I had to read the URL you linked to realise that you're not doing that at all. That's a bit confusing. You're installing the operator with helm and mongo with the operator.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I've posted an answer to my post which describes a little more detail in how I'm deploying the DB. In short, I'm not actually using the helm chart to deploy the DB, just the operator and CRDs. I then use a custom yml to create the database. The Helm chart did not allow for enough customization of the rs for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: I eventually managed to resolve the final remaining issue. When you deploy multiple replica sets using this method, you must make sure they each have a unique value for scramCredentialsSecretName.

<s>EDIT: Actually, this didn't fix the entire problem. It seems to work for a few hours then all the readiness probes for all rs start to fail again.</s>

It looks like you can deploy multiple operators and rs in a single namespace. What I was missing was linking the operators and rs together.

I also left out an important detail. I don't actually deploy the mongodb using that helm chart because the config options are too limited. At the bottom of the values.yaml there's a setting called  `createResource: false` which I have set to false. I then deploy a separate yaml that defines the mongo replicaset like so:

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: my-mongo-rs
spec:
  members: 3
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "5.0.5"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
    # tls:
    #   enabled: true
    #   certificateKeySecretRef:
    #     name: mongo-tls
    #   caConfigMapRef:
    #     name: mongo-ca
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: "mongodb-agent"
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 200m
                  memory: 500M
                limits: {}
            - name: "mongod"
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 1000m
                  memory: 5G
                limits: {}
          serviceAccountName: my-mongodb-database
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: data-volume
        spec:
          storageClassName: my-retainer-sc
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 20G
  # replicaSetHorizons:
  #   - external: myhostname.com:9000
  #   - external: myhostname.com:9001
  #   - external: myhostname.com:9002
  users:
    - name: my-mongo-user
      db: admin
      passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
        name: my-mongo-user-creds
      roles:
        - db: admin
          name: clusterAdmin
        - db: admin
          name: readWriteAnyDatabase
        - db: admin
          name: dbAdminAnyDatabase
        - db: admin
          name: userAdminAnyDatabase
        - db: admin
          name: root
      scramCredentialsSecretName: my-user-scram
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
```

Anywhere in this config where you see "my", I actually use my app name but I've genericized it for this post.

To link the operator and rs together, it's done using a name. In the operator yaml it's this line:

```
database:
  name: my-mongodb-database
```

That name creates a serviceaccount in kubernetes and you must define your database pod to use that specific serviceaccount. Otherwise, it tries to default to a serviceaccount named mongodb-database which either won't exist, or you'll end up with multiple rs using the same serviceaccount (therefore, the same operator).

And in the rs yaml it's this line:

```
serviceAccountName: my-mongodb-database
```

This will link it to the correct serviceaccount.